# Grep and delete content from a file or update with new file

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have requirement to grep data with unique keyword and delete the upper line with below two lines.

For example:

Source file:

```
{
  name: main
  phase: beta
}
{
  name: test
  phase: dev
}
```

I have used below command to grep the data:

```
grep -A2 -B1 main sourcefile
```

which gives me :

```
{
  name: main
  phase: beta
}
```

I have used with -v option but no luck ... its still show whole data.

```
grep -vA2 -vB1 main sourcefile
```

Then I print the line numbers with grep and try to delete the same with sed but that also not working.

```
for i in `grep -n -A2 -B1 main sourcefile | awk {'print $1'} | cut -b 1,2` do sed -e "$i"d sourcefile; done.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

trying to delete the data from a file with grep unique keyword and update the file

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Source file should be left with :

{                                                                                                                                                                    
  name: test                                                                                                                                   
  phase: dev                                                                                                                                   
}

Comment: Suggest you to edit your question and show this expected output in the question itself.

Comment: The input looks like "almost JSON". Can you change the input to be valid JSON (or at least a sequence of JSON entities)?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
awk -v RS='{[^}]*}\n' '{ORS = (RT ~ /:\s*main/ ? "" : RT)} 1' file

{
  name: test
  phase: dev
}
```

Here:

- `RS='{[^}]*}\n'` will set a `{...}\n` text as record separator.
- `ORS = (RT ~ /:\s*main/ ? "" : RT)` will set `ORS` to an empty string when we find `: main` in the `RT` otherwise `ORS` is set to `RT`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\n.*\bmain\b/{N;N;d};P;D' file
```

Open a two line window and if the second line contains the word `main`, append the next two lines and then delete the four lines in the pattern space.

If the second line does not contain the word `main`, print/delete the first and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{rec=rec $0 ORS} /^}$/{if (rec !~ /main/) printf "%s", rec; rec=""}' file
{
  name: test
  phase: dev
}
```

The above will work even if your data contains `{` or `}` in other contexts such as inside strings and no matter how many lines are in each `}`-terminated block. It assumes you're OK with substring matches on `main` (e.g. `mainstay` or `germain`), just like the `grep` command in your question would be - if that's wrong then just tighten the regexp to be more exclusive, e.g. `/name: *main\n/`.

Answer (score 0):

`ed` can easily make such relative changes:

```
printf '/main/-1;+3d\nw\nq\n' | ed -s sourcefile
```

or

```
ed -s sourcefile <<'EOD'
/main/-1;+3d
w
q
EOD
```

- find line matching regex and move to line above it
- delete that and next 3 lines
- save changes
- quit